# What is this hole on the F-22 Raptor?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, fighter, feature-identification, f-22

I noticed this little hole that is right in front of the cockpit window of the F-22 Raptor. In some photos, it seems to be closed, while in other photos, it's open.

Does anyone know (or think they know) what the purpose of this hole is? Is it a ram air intake for air conditioning? Or is this classified?

Here are examples:

Closed hole:
[image]

Open hole:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The appearance of being closed/open is a light trick; light reflecting off the tiny transparent window of the [**missile launch detector**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missile_approach_warning_system).

This detector typically sees in IR and would detect the plume of a heat-seeking missile. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_F-22_Raptor), the model used on the F-22 is AN/AAR-56 (IR based). (There are videos available on YouTube for its output; [example](https://youtu.be/rUj3JTe1nVI).)

In the below cutaway, it's label number 7. Note it says window**s**, so I suppose there's more than one for the different angles (after some eye strain I couldn't find another 7).

[image]
Source: [pinterest.com](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/524528687823913529/)

---

The F-35 uses the [AN/AAQ-37](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN/AAQ-37), below are the various locations:

[image]
Source: [daumcdn.net](https://t1.daumcdn.net/cfile/tistory/2453804E5220798017) (Korean)

Comment: I wasn't able to find another number 7 either, but I did find a number 44, which seems to be the same thing. Thanks for sharing the detailed diagram!